# Using one slicer (Date) with two different tables and two different data columns

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, powerbi-desktop, relation, slicers

I have several tables in my data model.

Among others I have the table

- "Sales" (with all sold products by customer, date and marketing source) and the table
- "Media Spend" (with all marketing sources and their budget per month).

**TABLE "SALES“**

**Product | Contract ID | Customer ID | Sales Date                      | Source**

A             | 001               | C1                    | dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss | Source A

B             | 002              | C2                    | dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss | Source B

B             | 003              | C1                    | dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss | Source B

C            | 004              | C3                    | dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss | Source C

D            | 005              | C6                    | dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss | Source F

**TABLE „MEDIA SPEND“**

**Source     | Spend | Campaign Month**

Source A   | 500 € | mm.yyyy

Source B   | 600 € | mm.yyyy

Source C   | 300 € | mm.yyyy

Source D   | 100 € | mm.yyyy

Source E   | 550 € | mm.yyyy

Source F   | 1,000 € | mm.yyyy        |

The tables are connected by the relation "Source".

It should be mentioned that the "Sales Date" is much more detailed (dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss) than the "Campaign month") (mm.yyyy).

This allows me to filter both customers and marketing budgets by "Source".
But at the same time I want to calculate / filter by Date (e.g. „Sales date“).
But this is not possible.

**How can I proceed to relate the two different columns in different tables?**

I have already tried the following

Build the Relation based on both Date-Columns
=> Problem shift from Date to Source

Second connection (besides "Source") created for the columns "Sales Date" and "Campaign" month.
=> The data model shows the connection as dashed. Otherwise there is no effect.

THANX!

Comment: Your question is well versed, however, do you have a dates table in your model, if you do, on which date/s columns is it linked to?

Comment: Hey, no I do not have a specific dates table. Do I need it? Is this the key to align two different date columns?

Comment: yes that is what you need. Especially for what you expect to see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dates table by selecting New Table when you're in Power BI as can be seen below:

[image: New Table]

Copy and paste the below and your dates table will be created:

```
DimDate = CALENDAR( DATE( 2018, 1, 1 ) , DATE( 2024, 12, 31 ) )
```

or

```
DimDate = CALENDARAUTO( 3 )
```

Both of which will provide you with the below result:

[image: Expected Result]

After creating this table, you can create additional columns using the following dax for each column:

```
CalendarYear = YEAR( DimDate[Date] )

CalendarMonthInt = MONTH( DimDate[Date] )

CalendarDay = DAY( DimDate[Date] )

CalendarMonthName = FORMAT( DimDate[Date], "mmmm" )

CalendarShortMonth = LEFT( DimDate[CalendarMonthName], 3 )

YearMonth = CONCATENATE( YEAR( DimDate[Date] ), FORMAT( MONTH( DimDate[Date] ), "00" ) )
```

After adding these columns, your result will look like this:

[image: Final Result]

Comment: Thank you, Birel! Wow, great help and perfect explanation.

One think is not clear for me: How do I align it with the tables „Sales“ and „Media“: They have already a relation.

And a relation of the Tables does not work, right?

Comment: @Florian, you need to link (create relationships) both their transaction dates to the dates table, then use the columns in your dates table to filter the data. That way you will filter both tables at once. If you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as the answer.